# How do I redirect a browser to a local file in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, firefox, redirect

I want firefox to open *C:\somefile.txt* on the local drive. I've tried response.redirect with the "file:///" prefix, but it just inserts "Object moved to here." into the page. I also want to htmlencode the path because it could contain special chars...

> **Edit:** To be clear: *C:\somefile.txt* is a file on the **client box** running the browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be honest I don't quite know why `Response.Redirect("file:///aaa")` isn't working for you. Without reading the RFC, or testing it myself, I don't know.

-- Edit:

Tested myself; definitely doesn't work.

Failing someone showing you how, you can just write write a link to it, or use some (admittedly lame) javascript (to be written to the client, instead of Redirecting) like so:

```
<script language="javascript">document.location = "file:///aaaa";</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't. Web pages are explicitly not allowed to link or redirect to local content. It's a security measure.